# Visualize distribution of requests by load balancer across multiple instances on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have my code running on App Engine Flex with 5 instances.

Is there a way we could graphically visualize the distribution of requests per instance wise.

The current dashboard doesn't display to the instance level and my client is interested to get an instance level view.

Answer (score 0):

At this time it is not possible to do something like that. However, I created a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/129330935) for this. I suggest you to star the Feature Request and every time there is an update you will be notified.